# How to generate a Drop down with an array of numbers in React -Semantic UI - Dropdown Component?

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I am trying to generate a dropdown with React semantic UI - Dropdown using an Array of numbers.
Below is my Code:

```
 render() {
    const myrange = [100, 200,300,500,1000,2000,3000,5000,7500,10000,15000, 20000, 25000];

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <List horizontal relaxed>
          <List.Item>
            <Checkbox
              style={{ paddingLeft: "1em", paddingBottom: "1em" }}
              label={this.props.title}
              checked={this.props.checked}
              onChange={this.props.handleChange}
            />
            <List.Content>
              <Dropdown
                      placeholder="Select"
                      fluid
                      search
                      selection
                      options={myrange.map(merange => ({ label: { merange },

                    }))}
                      // onChange={this.props.handleChange("category")}
                    />
```

The dropdown looks like the screenshot:
[image]

This code works and generates a list of blanks, would be nice to get the numbers displayed in the dropdown list ...

Any help will be highly appreciated here.

Comment: Inside `<Dropdown>` options prop is set to wrong values. options need values in the format ex. `options = [{ key: '100', text: '100', value: '100' }]` So please change your map function to return the list in given format.

Comment: For working example check this link https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown/#types-clearable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 return (
    <React.Fragment>
    <List horizontal relaxed>
    <List.Item>
      <Checkbox
        style={{ paddingLeft: "1em", paddingBottom: "1em" }}
        label="LABEL"
        checked='checked'
        // onChange={this.props.handleChange}
     ></Checkbox>
      <List.Content>
        <Dropdown
                placeholder="Select"
                fluid
                search
                selection
                options={myrange.map(merange => ({key: merange, text:merange, value: merange }))}
              />      
            </List.Content>
          </List.Item>
       </List>
      </React.Fragment>
  )
```

Like that.